# Active menu background color

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a vertical menu. It is .glossymenu . The menu item is accessed using css as .glossymenu a.menuitem . I want to change the background color when the menu item is selected or when the menu item is active. I am trying to use the following JQuery:

```
$(".glossymenu a.menuitem").click(function(){
  $(this).siblings(".active").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

But, I am unable to resolve my issue using this. Any ideas, how to change the background color of the menu item, when it is selected. It should not change when we click outside the menu item in blank area, when the menu is active. 
Thanks,
Prasad

Comment: please post your full html code? or else create a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is what your html looks like:

```
<ul class="glossymenu">
    <li><a class="menuitem active" href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a class="menuitem" href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a class="menuitem" href="#">Item</a></li>
</ul>​
```

And CSS like this:

```
.glossymenu li {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.glossymenu a {
    background-color: pink;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

.glossymenu .active {
    background-color: #bada55;
}​
```

Then your js would be this:

```
$('.glossymenu .menuitem').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.glossymenu .active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

The problem you might have been having is that `siblings()` wouldn't select any of the other anchors tags because they are not siblings of the anchor that has been clicked on.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Vestride/qhSQ4/

**EDIT:**

I made a new jsfiddle ([link](http://jsfiddle.net/Vestride/c8z2v/)) for you, but I'm a still very confused as to what you're attempting to do and what you mean by making the script more general.

Maybe this will help solve your problem. http://sixrevisions.com/javascript/20-excellent-javascript-navigation-techniques-and-examples/

Comment: Thank you Vestride. This applies to only one menu item. I want general method, which is applicable to all menu items. My HTML code for the menu is as follows: <div class="glossymenu">
<a class="menuitem" href="#">Home</a>
<a class="menuitem submenuheader" href="#">Text Pages</a>
<div class="submenu">
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Menus</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Menus</a></li>

Comment: glossymenu is the main class, menuitem is sub class for both expandable and non expandable menu's. class="menuitem submenuheader" is for the expandable classes. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use jQuery's hover function.

```
$(".glossymenu a.menuitem").hover(function(){
  $(this).siblings(".active").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Active state is available in CSS and it much better to use that one instead.

```css
a.menuitem:active { background-color: #c00; }
```